# Shibboleth nameID format emailaddress

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I am working on integrating a SAML vendor (Freshdesk) into my Shibboleth environment. My issue is the nameID format is empty.

Reading through the documentation on my vendor, they want `<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">example@test.freshdesk.com</saml:NameID>`

I've added this format to my metadata, as well as inside an attribute encoder in my attribute definition for email.

However in my debug logs I am getting this message:

```
2015-08-12 18:01:47,005 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.attribute.encoding.AbstractSAMLAttributeEncoder:154] - Beginning to encode attribute email 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,006 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.attribute.encoding.SAMLEncoderSupport:73] - Encoding value martinb@psd401.net of attribute email 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,006 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.attribute.encoding.AbstractSAMLAttributeEncoder:191] - Completed encoding 1 values for attribute email 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,007 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.saml2.profile.impl.AddAttributeStatementToAssertion:117] - Profile Action AddAttributeStatementToAssertion: Adding constructed AttributeStatement to Assertion _0594703842dee0ce77c66 
3989574661b 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,008 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.profile.impl.AddNameIDToSubjects:286] - Profile Action AddNameIDToSubjects: Attempting to add NameID to outgoing Assertion Subjects 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,009 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.common.profile.logic.AbstractNameIDPolicyPredicate:218] - Policy checking disabled for NameIDPolicy with Format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,009 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.common.profile.logic.MetadataNameIdentifierFormatStrategy:82] - Metadata specifies the following formats: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress] 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,010 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile.logic.DefaultNameIdentifierFormatStrategy:100] - Configuration specifies the following formats: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress] 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,010 - DEBUG [net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile.logic.DefaultNameIdentifierFormatStrategy:121] - Filtered non-metadata-supported formats from configured formats, leaving: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAd 
dress] 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,010 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.profile.impl.AddNameIDToSubjects:323] - Profile Action AddNameIDToSubjects: Candidate NameID formats: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress] 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,011 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.profile.impl.AddNameIDToSubjects:396] - Profile Action AddNameIDToSubjects: Trying to generate NameID with Format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,011 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.common.profile.impl.ChainingNameIdentifierGenerator:106] - Trying to generate identifier with Format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress 
2015-08-12 18:01:47,011 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.profile.impl.AddNameIDToSubjects:341] - Profile Action AddNameIDToSubjects: Unable to generate a NameID, leaving empty
```

I have been unable to find the cause of the AddNameIDToSubjects error, why is it leaving the NameID empty? Is it a problem with my Attribute Encoder?

```
 <resolver:AttributeDefinition id="email" xsi:type="ad:Simple" 
              sourceAttributeID="mail" >
        <resolver:Dependency ref="psdldap" />


        <resolver:AttributeEncoder 
                xsi:type="enc:SAML2StringNameID" 
                xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute:encoder" 
                nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />

        <resolver:AttributeEncoder 
                xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" 
                name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:email"/>
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder 
                xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" 
                nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" 
                name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" friendlyName="email"/>
    </resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAML2AttributeSourcedGenerator should be configured in `saml-nameid.xml`

```xml
<!-- SAML 2 NameID Generation -->
<util:list id="shibboleth.SAML2NameIDGenerators">

    <ref bean="shibboleth.SAML2TransientGenerator" />

    <!-- Uncommenting this bean requires configuration in saml-nameid.properties. -->
    <!--
    <ref bean="shibboleth.SAML2PersistentGenerator" />
    -->

    <bean parent="shibboleth.SAML2AttributeSourcedGenerator"
        p:format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
        p:attributeSourceIds="#{ {'email'} }" />

</util:list>
```

More details in Shibboleth Wiki in [Custom Identified Configuration](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/NameIDGenerationConfiguration#NameIDGenerationConfiguration-CustomCustomIdentifierGeneration) section.